# Splash Screen to support both 1280X768 and 1280x720

Tags: android, xml, pixel

I am trying to create a splash screen for android.
My question is the Note 2 takes a format of 1280 X 720 n 1280 X 768, and since they are both XHDPI format, the splash screen picture will be put in the XHDPI folder.  Since the splash screen covers the entire page, How can I make sure that both version gets the right image if I I were to put both pictures in xHdpi folder?

Comment: Just let Android handle the scaling on a single image. If you set your ImageView and its parent's layout height/width attributes to match_parent and make sure you use the appropriate scaleType

Comment: or set it as background, instead of src, so that it's automatically stretched to fill the container.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageView with layout_height and layout_width as match_parent and use scaleType = "centerCrop". This will do the trick for you.

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/containerRL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/splash"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
></ImageView>
```